# Click usando Webscraping com Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Estou iniciando meus estudos com Webscraping e estou com o problema na hora de dar um segundo clique em uma nova pagina.

Estou tentando acessar meu email usando Selenium, consigo preencher o meu e-mail e clicar para seguir para proxima pagina onde consigo preencher o campo com minha senha, ate aqui tudo normal. O problema surgi quando tenho q clicar em outro botao para entrar, consigo fazer isso.

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver

#Acessando o link
driver = webdriver.Chrome(`executable_path='/Users/gabrielmizuno/Desktop/chromedriver'`)
driver.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1545089604&rver=7.0.6737.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fauthRedirect%3dtrue%26nlp%3d1%26RpsCsrfState%3df53acbd7-cdac-5727-facb-5c96b414a0ec&id=292841&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=90015')

#Preenchendo email e clicando
email = driver.find_element_by_id('i0116')
email.send_keys('MEU E-MAIL')
driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()

#Preenchendo senha e clicando
senha = driver.find_element_by_id('i0118')
senha.send_keys('MINHA SENHA')
driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()
```

[image: Elementos do ultimo botão]

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi... Ao preencher os valores de login e clicar, ele em seguida preenche a senha e não clica?

Comment: Exatamente isso, o email e senha foram preenchidos de maneira correta mas na hora de dar o ultimo clique ele não clica.

Comment: Pode parecer obvio, mas ja verificou se o ID no qual esta clicando existe? tente verificar  oq esta chegando no "driver.find_element_by_id" na ultima linha, caso exista o problema é assincronismo.

Comment: mandei uma resposta para o seu problema, tente executar e me diga se funcionou blz?

Comment: Teliz dei uma verificada é o ID esta certo

Comment: Após preencher a senha consegue logar com o apertar do botão enter?

Comment: Ola Bulfaitelo essa ideia do Enter deu certo dps de colocar meu e-mail, mas na hora de dar Enter na senha nao aconteceu nada

Answer (score 2):

Verifiquei que esse mesmo botão possui um `class="btn btn-block btn-primary"`, você pode usar o class como parâmetro do segundo click para resolver o seu problema!

Comment: Ola Andre vi q existe esse class mas como estou começando não estou conseguindo acessar, poderia me dar um outra ajuda?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente se colocar

```
time.sleep(2)

#Preenchendo senha e clicando
senha = driver.find_element_by_id('i0118')
senha.send_keys('MINHA SENHA')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()
```

Ele efetua o click